# If $x=111...1(20 digits), y=333...3(10 digits), z=222..2(20 digits)$, find $\frac{x-y^2}{z}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

**My Solution**

$$x=\frac 19(10^{20}-1)$$
$$y=\frac 13 (10^{10}-1)$$
$$z=\frac 29 (10^{20}-1)$$

then $x-y^2$ will be 
$$\frac 29 (10^{10}-1)$$
Dividing this by $z$
$$\frac{10^{10}-1}{10^{20}-1}$$
$$=\frac{1}{10^{10}+1}$$
The right answer is 1, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Title: $y_2$. Is it $y^2$?

Comment: If the problem is stated correctly (and $y_2$ is meant to by $y^2$) then your solution is correct.

Comment: The answer is indeed $9.99999999900000000009999999999...$

Comment: "The right answer is 1"  Sez who?  If $1$ is the right answer what is the right question?  You have $y_2$ in your title but $y^2$ in your question.

Comment: I meant $y^2$. It was a typo

Comment: @Aditya, I'm sure the right answer is not $1$.

Comment: The answer is $1$ if $z = 222\cdots2$ ($10$ digit). What you got is correct for the question mentioned by you.